# Animation looks pixelated on safari browser and IE11

Tags: css, css-animations

Animation i've created works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but is pixelated on Safari (version 10.1.1) and IE11.

Tried using translateZ() / translate3d() so the gpu can render the animations but nothing happened.

I've avoided using top, left props. Had an idea of using the will-change prop but it doesn't take animation as a value.

Removing the border radius would fix the rendering issue.

Can someone explain the cause of this and is there a solution to fix this issue?

https://codepen.io/imrdev/pen/awBZOW

html ->

```
<div class="dot"></div>
```

css - >

```
  /* KEYFRAME ANIMATION */
  @keyframes ease {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0) rotate(0);
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(4)
    rotate(.01deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(0) rotate(0);
    }
  }

  @keyframes ease2 {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0) rotate(0);
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(6)
    rotate(.01deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(0) rotate(0);
    }
  }

.dot {
  $scale-duration: 15s;

  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    content: "";
    background: red;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: inherit;
    opacity:.3;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }

  &::before {
    animation: ease 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  }
  &::after {
    animation: ease2 5s ease-in-out infinite both $scale-duration/15;
  }
}
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: I removed some properties, and this looks the same for me on Chrome and IE: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQpGoW

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough reputation so i can't comment yet, so sorry if this doesn't qualify as a proper answer, but have you tried changing the size to something bigger than 7px and use eg `scale(1)` instead of `scale(4)`?

if you need to scale the width and height up by 4 or 6, why not just double the original size and scale up by 2 ?

I wouldn't be surprise if safari doesn't really scale the size up, but kinda like "zooms in" and since the original size is just 7 x 7 px it gets pixelated when "zoomed in"

and regarding to the will-change: you wouldn't use "animation" but "transform"